# how do I add a comment on a wordpress post using wp rest api v2?

Tags: java, android, wordpress, api, kotlin

I want to add comments on the wordpress web post from the Android APP using the Rest API : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool called [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

For more information on how to work with postman and wordpress, see [postman and wp-rest-api](https://wp-oauth.com/docs/how-to/using-postman-and-wp-rest-api/).